# How to convert ANSI text to Unicode correctly without installing language pack?

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have a CSV file in Traditional Chinese and it is coded as ANSI. The file can be read correctly on Traditional Chinese Windows versions. But when I open it on Windows 10 English version, it looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way  to convert ANSI text to Unicode correctly in C# without installing language pack onto the English Windows version?

Comment: It would be better that you could post this at another forum like `SuperUser`

Comment: How are you display the results?  The issue is not with the c# code.  The viewer you are using is not support the font.  If results is being displayed in VS than you just need to set VS property to view with different language.

Comment: So-called `ANSI` is a Microsoft misnomer. Please use [edit] button to share output from `REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage" -v *CP` on *Traditional **Chinese** Windows version*.

Comment: Try loading the file in an Notepad++ and selecting Encoding->Characters Sets->Chinese->Big5(Traditional).  Does it display correctly?

Comment: Is there a way to do that in C# to convert?

Comment: First step is to determine what encoding the text is actually in. Once you've done that, just use a `StreamReader` configured with an appropriate `Encoding` instance to match the encoding of the text. See duplicate.